# SWT TableViewer summary row

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

How can I add summary row in `TableViewer` (or different Viewer from SWT), which (row) will be containing sum of all rows in proper column?

And by the way, the next question. Is it possible to set multiline header in `TableViewer`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no special way to do this.

Your table Content Provider will have to return an object containing the summary data.